# Finding a Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I'm trying to find the optical distribution for the following data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z_cSu7w8tlz_uEYHr8Y0fFBTwLNo4jtp/view?usp=sharing

As there are a lot of points, the only way to make a quick Histogram is to use the following command that includes lower and upper bounds/limits

```
 pEx = Histogram[{dataEx}, {-10 10^6, 10 10^6, 2 10^5}, PlotRange -> {{-10 10^6, 10 10^6}, All}]
```

[image]

If I now ask for the corresponding distribution, through the following command:

```
FindDistribution[dataEx]
```

I obtain

```
CauchyDistribution[10787.5, 3.13764*10^6]
```

However, if I now plot the Cauch distribution above -- with an amplitude scaling factor -- i.e.,

```
fit[x_] := 2.5 10^10 PDF[CauchyDistribution[10787.533402804394`, 3.13763790539067`*^6], x]
```

I obtain

[image]

which clearly disagree with the original data.

However, I have notice however that this distribution fits quite well the region far from the origin, i.e., by redefining now

```
fit[x_] := .55 10^10 PDF[CauchyDistribution[10787.533402804394`, 3.13763790539067`*^6], x]
```

I obtain

[image]

which clearly give us a good match with the tail of the distribution.

Therefore, I'm wondering whether I'm doing something wrong here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably `FindDistribution` uses something akin to least-squares. Since you have way more points "far from the origin", the points near the center carry little weight, so the fit is poor there

Comment: That makes sense -- would you know how to fit only around the origin?

Comment: @denis Can you please grant public access to the gDrive link. I am unable to access it.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Oh, I'm sorry. I've just fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @denis Have you tried `FindDistribution` on the subset of the data that is used in `Histogram`? Filter the data to be in the range `{-10 10^6, 10 10^6}`.

Comment: `FindDistribution` does not use least squares (nor is least squares even appropriate for fitting a probability distribution).  You should use the `"PDF"` option in "Histogram" so that you won't have to guess as to a scaling factor.  The area for the histogram and the pdf will both be 1.

Comment: Maybe describing more about what you need and why tossing over 30% of your data is appropriate would be helpful.  (Over 30% of the sample points are outsize the range of -10^7 to +10^7.)  Also, what do you mean by "optical" ?  If you meant "optimal", I'm not sure what you mean by that either.

Comment: The data look more Laplace distributed to me. `LaplaceDistribution` has a tall peak and larger kurtosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dataEx = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/test.dat"] // Flatten;
```

Since you are interested in matching the distribution of the data in the interval `{-10^7, 10^7}` filter the data to that interval.

```
dataEx2 = Select[dataEx, -10^7 <= # <= 10^7 &];

Length /@ {dataEx, dataEx2}

(* {50000, 34069} *)
```

About 1/3 of the data is outside the range.

Use [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) for the distribution

```
dist2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[dataEx2];
```

Comparing the distributions,

```
Show[
 Histogram[{dataEx2}, {-10^7, 10^7, 2*^5},
  "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[dist2, x], {x, -10^7, 10^7},
  PlotRange -> All],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An `ExponentialPowerDistribution` looks like a good fit, even if a little shallow in the far tails:

```
data = Select[Flatten[Import["test.dat"]], -10^7 < # < 10^7 &];
dist = EstimatedDistribution[data, ExponentialPowerDistribution[k, m, s]]
Show[
 Histogram[data, {-10^7, 10^7, 200000}, "PDF", PlotTheme -> "Classic"],
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -10^7, 10^7}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
]
```

[image: exponential power distribution]